# Promise resolve confusion

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

When I resolve the promise, the function should continue being executed:

```
function test(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        resolve(5)
        setTimeout(()=>{console.log(7)}, 2000}
    })
}
```

And then I invoke the function like this

```
test().then(console.log);
```

So it prints 5, and then after 2 seconds, it prints 7, as I expected.
But if I work with sync thing after resolve() it works differently:

```
function test(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        resolve(5)
        for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            console.log(i)
    })
}
```

Now it prints the numbers from 0 to 100, and then it prints 5. But I expected it to return 5 through resolve() and only then print all the rest stuff.

Comment: No. You should do `return resolve(5)` and after that you don't do anything. Otherwise, why are you resolving....

Comment: @yBrodsky not true. You can use resolve without explicitly returning it. The only important thing to `return` is the `new Promise`.

Comment: The keyword is should. Any practical example where you want to continue doing stuff after resolve, inside the promise?.

Comment: It's because of then-callback is being executed after Promise body. `resolve()` is the way to `.then` cb which is executed last

Comment: @yBrodsky, I receive a lot of found peers, and if one of them is the one I'm looking for I will resolve it straight away. But the function will continue working with other peers.

Comment: Oh so if I want to work with other peers, I just send them to another async function and it works just fine. (well should work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code gives the expected outcome.  When you resolve immediately with 5, the function isn't finished executing yet, so it runs the rest of the code.  Once done, the call stack is empty and the asynchronous `then` gets its chance to run.  The difference between the two programs is that the second one logs immediately because it does not have to wait for the function to finish to execute.  It's synchronous.

Answer (score -1):

I think it has to do with javascript's [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ). With the link you can watch amazing video about event loop in JS.
I'm not sure, but it seems like what's inside `resolve()` is called asynchronously, but for loop is sync, that's why what's inside resolve is put into a queue and for loop is executed immediately. After "normal" execution process finished, resolve does it's job, returning 5.

In the example with `setTimeout` you've put the code into queue, but for later(2000ms) execution. Since 5 doesn't do anything, it's returned right away(asynchronously though) and after 2 seconds your code is run. Wath the video.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. 
Nodejs runs code from left to right.
First it gives me a function with resolve reject as arguments,  then it executes this function. It resolves the value. Then it encounters a synchronous for loop, therefore it has to execute it synced. Then it returns an already resolved promise that I apply method then on. then() executes the callback when the promise is resolved. It is already resolved. And it prints my resolved value
 If you use callbacks it will be different:

```
function test(callback){
    callback(7)
    for(let i = 0; i<100; i++){
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

it will first, print(7) and only then all the rest numbers
But it works only if you know that the callback will be invoked once. Because otherwise, it will break the logic.

Comment: Obviously, because callbacks are synchronous and promises are implemented asynchronously.. But this doesn't answer your question - why it loops first and then resolves the promise.

Comment: It kinda does because now I know the difference exists because of the Promise's implementation

Comment: Probably now I just have to google how promises are made

Answer (score -2):

So, a few things I wanted to make sure we're on the same page. Your `test` function's `setTimeout` is asynchronous. Yes, it's inside a promise, but you've sent it to the event loop in an uncontrolled manner.

`setTimeout(()=>{console.log(7)}, 2000} //not controlled in your first function`

Whatever you place in `resolve` is the only thing that gets controlled by the promise. The way you're using the promise is not how they are supposed to be used. You might have to go back to basics and read up on it some more if this confuses you.

edit: I seemed to have no articulated myself properly, and thus have garnered quite a bit of salt. Better explanation:

You should treat a `promise` how you would a return statement. A promise function should not perform any other output operation except a single `resolve` statement. This can then be synchronously controlled in subsequent operations in *another* function. Key word is another.

```
function test(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        resolve(5)
    })
}

function loopTest() {
  test().then( (num) => {
    console.log(num)
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log(i)
    }
  })
} // what you were trying to actually accomplish

loopTest()
```

Comment: Thanks. But sorry I don't quite get what you are trying to say under 'uncontrolled'